# How to use CDATA correctly?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to use [CDATA[]]> Correctly as i want to include URLS in my activity, but it does not show up on my application and i have no idea why.

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong? do i need to add something in the .java file also?

heres a pic of the output

[image]

> string.xml

```
 <string name="about_body"><![CDATA[
        <b>Dipolog TourGuide and TranslatorApp</b><br>
        Author: <b><a href="https://www.facebook.com/tomstorey66">Thomas Storey</a></b><br>
        <br>
        Thesis Team : <b>Thomas Storey, Christian Acalain, Mary Grace Lee</b></a><br>
        Instructor of ABC: <b>Mr Jay Arr Saile</b></a><br>
        <br><br>
        <b>Many thanks for code and ideas to:</b><br>
        This application was made for Thesis Studies II under there instructor Mr Jay Arr Saile during the school year of 2015-2016<br><br>
        Dipolog Tour Guide and Translator was made for tourists who are visiting or planning to visit Dipolog
        <br><br>
        Many thanks for code and ideas to:
        <b><a href="https://www.sourcecodester.com>SourceCodester</a></b><br>
        <i>Established 2003-Present</i><br><br>
        <b><a href="https://www.googleplay.com>Googleplay</a></b><br>
        <i>Established 1999-Present</i><br><br>
        <b><a href="www.stackoverflow.com>Stack Overflow</a></b><br>
        <i>Forum members assisting in debugging
        Est 2005-Present</i><br><br>

        Google, Google Play and the Google Maps logo are registered trademarks of Google Inc.

    ]]></string>
```

> content5.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="learn.navdrawbase.MyAbout"
    tools:showIn="@layout/my_about">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/title_about"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:text="@+id/about_body"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />


        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> MyAbout.java

```
public class MyAbout extends BaseActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_about);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "About", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });


    //Set nav drawer selected to second item in list
    mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(4).setChecked(true);

}

((TextView) findViewById(R.id.about_body)).setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about_body)));
```

Comment: textviews don't parse html.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Change your linear-layout to below inside relative-layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_about"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/about_body"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="@string/about_body"
                android:textSize="14sp" />


        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

---

After that set text below way in activity **onCreate**

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.about_body)).setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about_body)));
```

---

***EDITED***

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_about);

        /**
         * YOUR OTHER CODE
         *
         * */

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.about_body)).setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about_body)));
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but in my activity im recieving the error "Invalid method declaration, return type required"
 i have edited in my .java file to the post

Comment: @Storey: add your activity code in question & its not related to this question but still add code

Comment: ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.about_body)).setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about_body))); use this line inside onCreate of your activity check edited answer i have added code

Comment: ah, perfect! thankyou for your time & sorry for my silly mistake, have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

**Yeah you have to give String reference to text property. Using +id you make new id in R file.**

**you can achive that html text code directly also see below link you get idea from that**

[Android TextView supported Html Tags](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

**And Second things is that you miss some tag to close see anchor tag   you did not put close bracket in that**

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ID of the string, but you need to use the actual string, which is @string/about_body rather than @+id/about_body.  The rest does look correct.

Comment: thankyou, it is now showing! but i have occured 2 other problems.

1. the CDATA is not working as all of the <b> and <p> etc are showing
2. it is not correctly formatted 

pls see the picture
http://imgur.com/kTtvcMs